export bone as fbx causes wrong scaling when "add leaf bones" is turned off
When I export bones as fbx file and deselect "add leaf bones", the bones are exported with incorrect sizes. The bones are all the same size. I pressed ctrl + a before exporting and pressed apply all transformations and delta transformations, but it still happens. How can I solve that?
